# How do you scroll a GridLayout inside Kivy ScrollView?

Tags: python, kivy

At the moment this is my kv code that is not scrollable:

```
BoxLayout:
    id: bl
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 10, 10
    row_default_height: '48dp'
    row_force_default: True
    spacing: 10, 10

    GridLayout:
        id: layout_content
        cols: 1
        row_default_height: '20dp'
        row_force_default: True
        spacing: 0, 0
        padding: 0, 0

        Label:
            text: 'You don''t have any downloads. Please add new download from Home screen'
```

How do you make the above kv code scrollable? I know that Kivy ScrollView only accept one child, and I have already make GridLayout to be child of a new ScrollView. But it's not working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [documentation for ScrollView](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html?highlight=scrollview#managing-the-content-size-and-position) you have to disable at least one of the ScrollView's child size_hint:

```
<Controller>:
    layout_content: layout_content
    BoxLayout:
        id: bl
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '48dp'
        row_force_default: True
        spacing: 10, 10
        ScrollView:
            size: self.size
            GridLayout:
                id: layout_content
                size_hint_y: None
                cols: 1
                row_default_height: '20dp'
                row_force_default: True
                spacing: 0, 0
                padding: 0, 0

                Label:
                    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
```

And bind the layout's size to adapt itself:

```
# main.py

class Controller(FloatLayout):
    layout_content=ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout_content.bind(minimum_height=self.layout_content.setter('height'))
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I just did! :) Thanks.. @syntax_error? :D

Comment: Yeah almost: the devil is in the details, specially with kv stuff :)

Comment: Got to say, I kinda hoping that Kivy-Designer become their main intention soon. It will definitely help us design the interface with ease. Unfortunately, that project seems to be in dormant state. I miss PyQt this way..

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I get an error  `Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
     edlApp().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 766, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "main.py", line 20, in build
     return Controller()
   File "main.py", line 16, in __init__
     self.layout_content.bind(minimum_height=self.layout_content.setter('height'))
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
`

Comment: It should be `ScrollView:` <- With a colon

Comment: It worked for me, but i want to know why it is necessary to bind that ```minimum_height``` property?

Comment: A simpler method is to bind the height to the minimum height inside the kv file: `height: self.minimum_height`. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47600781/6362595)

Comment: For anyone wanting a ScrollView that scrolls **horizontally** instead of **vertically**, use `width: self.minimum_width` instead.

Answer (score 0):

works and fixes issue of scrollview not resizing length with window when maximized. No kv for those needing it without

```
kivy.require('1.11.1')
      
class ScrollTest(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
        Window.bind(on_maximize=self.testing)
        
        self.size_hint = (1,None)
        self.pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5,'top': 1}
        self.size = (Window.width,Window.height)

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 1
        self.inside.size_hint_y= None
        self.inside.spacing = 10
        
        self.inside.bind(minimum_height=self.inside.setter('height'))#checks when window maximized
        
        for i in range(1,5):
            self.submit = Button(text='something',size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            self.submit.bind(on_press=self.wPressed)
            self.inside.add_widget(self.submit)
        
        self.add_widget(self.inside)
        
    def wPressed(self,instance):
        self.submit = Button(text='something',size_hint_y=None, height=40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.wPressed)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.submit)
            
    def testing(self,instance):
        self.size= (Window.width,Window.height)

        
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        
        '''Creation of login screen'''
        self.login_page = ScrollTest()
        screen = Screen(name= 'Login')
        screen.add_widget(self.login_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)
        
        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button