# GridLayout Not Scrolling in Kivy

Tags: python, scrollview, kivy

Please tell me why this doesn't work, the whole program works fine, it uses a function inside the main program to get it's text, but it won't scroll so the user won't be able to view the entire output.

```
<AnswerScreen@Screen>:
    input_textb: input_textb
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (1, None)
        do_scroll_y: True
        do_scroll_x: False
        bar_width: 4
        GridLayout:
            padding: root.width * 0.02, root.height * 0.02
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: 1
            height: self.minimum_height
            Label:
                id: input_textb
                text: ""
                font_size: root.height / 25
                text_size: self.width, None
```

Edit:

- I had already tried doing the same as many previous answers, in the particular one mentioned in the comments, I got an error saying "NoneType" has no attribute "bind".
- I removed the size hint, it still doesn't work, but thanks anyway.
- The text is definitely long enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you scroll a GridLayout inside Kivy ScrollView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686631/how-do-you-scroll-a-gridlayout-inside-kivy-scrollview)

Comment: Why have you set the ScrollView size_hint_y to None? Try removing that line.

Comment: Also, I assume you set the Label text to be long - in this example, the GridLayout won't be large enough to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the label's size is not set, which i agree can be confusing at first, Label has a widget size (`size` as all widgets) and a `texture_size`, which is set to the actual size of the displayed text, kivy doesn't relate these two in any particular way at first, and it's up to you to decide how one influences the other, you did half of the work in setting text_size to `(width, None)`, which forces the texture into having the width of the widget, but you are missing the other part of the deal, which is that you want to be the widget to be as tall as the generated texture. For this size to be effective, you also have to disable size_hint_y for Label, since it's in a `GridLayout`.

```
        Label:
            id: input_textb
            text: ""
            font_size: root.height / 25
            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            size_hint_y: None
```

and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a value for the property `scroll_y` of the ScrollView between 0 and 1.