# Spreadsheet with KIVY in python

Tags: kivy, spreadsheet

I would like to implement an excel-like table in a 'Screen' object (child of 'ScreenManager') , with a larger resolution than the device's size. And the user can move / zoom + / zoom - / copy-paste cells, rows ... with its finger.
I have no idea of how to do that.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: No. I have really no idea of how to do that in kivy

Comment: Consider using a ScrollView Layout.

Comment: Link to [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686631/how-do-you-scroll-a-gridlayout-inside-kivy-scrollview) asking about ScrollView